# How do I tell a SED to regenerate the encryption key?

Tags: security, self-encrypting-drive, opal, sedutil, cryptographic-erase

I recently purchased a Crucial MX300 to use as a boot drive, and I want to take advantage of its self encrypting functionality. I've been reading up on SEDs and I understand they use a Data Encryption Key or DEK (sometimes called a Media Encryption Key) and an Authorization Key which encrypts the DEK.

From the [TCG Opal FAQ on SEDs](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/commonly-asked-questions-answers-self-encrypting-drives/) (emphasis added):

> A: The encryption key is generated on board the drive and NEVER LEAVES
>   THE DRIVE. The manufacturer does NOT retain or even have access to the
>   key. Moreover, you do not have to trust it. When putting an SED into
>   service **it is considered good practice to start by directing the SED
>   to regenerate its encryption key.** Doing this before loading any
>   software on the drive eliminates the possibility of the drive
>   manufacturer ,or anyone else who might have had a chance to access the
>   drive before the current owner, acquiring any secret, like the
>   encryption key, that could be later used to break into the user data.

My question is, how do I direct the SED to regenerate its encryption key? The only free tool I know about for working with SEDs is [sedutil](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil). I have been all over the documentation for that tool and I can't find anything about regenerating the DEK.

Does anyone know how to instruct the SED to regenerate the encryption key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: I don't have SED drive nor have I tried the below. Please use at your own risk**

From:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Self-Encrypting_Drives

in section **Secure disk erasure**:

> Simply passing a cryptographic disk erasure (or crypto erase) command
>   (after providing the correct authentication credentials) will have the
>   drive self-generate a new random encryption key (DEK) internally. This
>   will permanently discard the old key, thus rendering the encrypted
>   data irrevocably un-decryptable.

From this:

- https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1636022/html/GUID-68D4D72F-8884-4AAE-B8C6-CCF0A8D6129B.html

> Using the PSID to perform a factory reset causes all disk parameters
>   to be reset to factory original settings, including the following:
>
> - The encryption key used to encrypt and decrypt the data on the media
>     is changed to an unknown value.

From this:

- https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/blob/master/linux/PSIDRevert_LINUX.txt (Linux)
- https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/PSID-Revert (Windows)

you have this:

> Warning: This function will erase all of your data 
>   ...

Linux:

```
setutil-cli --yesIreallywanttoERASEALLmydatausingthePSID <PSIDALLCAPSNODASHES> /dev/sd?
```

Windows:

```
sedutil-cli -–yesIreallywanttoERASEALLmydatausingthePSID <YOURPSID> \\.\PhysicalDrive?
```

> You should see INFO: revertTper completed successfully.
>
> If you get a message that says NOT_AUTHORIZED you entered the PSID wrong.

Hope this helps.